# Error: Object with ID 'Participant:com.test.participant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to change the value of the Participant using a transaction.
It throws the error "Error: Object with ID 'Participant:com.test.participant' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist"

Please let me know what is the issue. Was there any change in the new version ??

Base cto :

```
namespace com.test.base

enum Gender {
 o MALE
 o FEMALE
 o OTHER
}

/**
 * A concept for a simple street address
 */
concept Address {
  o String address
  o Boolean isAddressValidated 
}
```

Participant CTO :

```
/**
 * New model file
 */

namespace com.test.participant
import com.test.base.*

abstract participant User{
  o  String lastname
 }

participant Customer identified by userId extends User {
  o String userId 
  o String fName
  o Address address
}

transaction ValidateAddress {
  o Boolean isAddressValidated
  --> Customer customer
}
```

Js file:

```
 /**
     * Sample transaction processor function.
     * @param {com.test.participant.ValidateAddress} tx The sample transaction instance.
     * @transaction
     */
    async function sampleTransaction(tx) { 
         tx.customer.address.isAddressValidated = tx.isAddressValidated;

        const participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('com.test.participant','Costumer');
  await participantRegistry.update(tx.customer);

     }
```

Test values:

```
{
  "$class": "com.test.participant.Customer",
  "uId": "customer1",
  "fName": "Pradeep",
  "address": {
    "$class": "com.test.base.Address",
    "address": "",
    "isAddressValidated": false
  },
  "lastname": "P"
}

{
  "$class": "com.test.participant.ValidateAddress",
  "isAddressValidated": true,
  "customer": "resource:com.test.participant.Customer#customer1"
}
```

Download bna file as well in the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NQYELmLzMyuN2V4yvDhUoLWackjs18Fa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: think your problem is simple - your participant registry in your txn code is actually `const participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('com.test.participant','Customer')` - that's why the registry error/complaint you posted appears

Answer (score 2):

I edited `two` things in you network definition, NOTE: I tested this on Hyperldger Playground and it worked

1. Changed `uId` to `userId` in your test data
2. Cleared Customer typos in your transactions code where you get your Participant registry.

So I came up with this code after all the changes

```
namespace com.test.base

enum Gender {
 o MALE
 o FEMALE
 o OTHER
}

/**
 * A concept for a simple street address
 */
concept Address {
  o String address
  o Boolean isAddressValidated  
}


/**
 * New model file
*/

namespace com.test.participant
import com.test.base.*

abstract participant User{
  o  String lastname
 }

participant Customer identified by userId extends User {
  o String userId 
  o String fName
  o Address address
}

transaction ValidateAddress {
  o Boolean isAddressValidated
  --> Customer customer
}
```

The test data looks as follows

```
{
  "$class": "com.test.participant.Customer",
  "userId": "customer1",
  "fName": "Pradeep",
  "address": {
    "$class": "com.test.base.Address",
    "address": "New York",
    "isAddressValidated": true
  },
  "lastname": "P"
}
```

For the transaction
I did not change anything. I hope this helps

Comment: Small spell mistake caused so much time :P.  Can we have some plugin to catch hold this errors in future. Really helpful developers

Comment: you should use playground for testing, it helps avoid some error but not all. Also use Visual Studio Code Hyperledger Plugin